# How can I find missing or mismatched braces / parens in emacs?

Tags: emacs

When my code fails to compile and tells me that I am likely missing a closed brace, is there an easy way to find it in emacs?

Comment: One would also be interested if there is some sort of M-x fix-parens.

Comment: good idea. I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328163/is-there-a-way-to-automate-fixing-mismatched-parens-in-emacs-m-x-fix-parens

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For languages like C, C++, and Java, the command `check-parens` will check parens (`()`), brackets (`[]`), and braces (`{}`):

```
M-x check-parens <RET>
```

The point will move to a bracketing character that is unmatched, and the status line will report the problem.

It's a good idea to use this in conjunction with `show-paren-mode` as others have said.

Answer (score 18):

If you use following code in your .emacs then if you are before or after a bracket it will highlight all of the expression between them - might help you find mismatched brackets.

```
(show-paren-mode t)
(setq show-paren-style 'expression)
```

Comment: really nice feature - thanks to you and @robert for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

[Show Paren Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode) will highlight bad braces as you type them.  I don't know how to find them after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

I use the [rainbow-delimiters](https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters) package mode exactly for that reason.

My settings:

```
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(set-face-attribute 'rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face nil
            :foreground "red"
            :inherit 'error
            :box t)
```