# Is there a way to automate fixing missing parens in Emacs? M-x fix-parens?

Tags: emacs

*updated following Dirk's suggestion*

After finding out about emacs' check-parens and show-parens modes in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319712/how-can-i-find-missing-or-mismatched-braces-parens-in-emacs), the value of a fix-missing-parens mode, a comment raised the point that it would be nice to automate the process of finding and adding missing or extra parens.

Is there a way to automate fixing such mismatched parens?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in general.  How do you know which paren (of a mis-matched pair) is the correct one?  If you're missing one, how do you know *where* to put it?

Comment: good point. I guess there is still a role for us humans

Comment: Trey: Technically we can still show the possible locations (as a guess work)  based upon the language syntax.

Comment: `M-x fix-parens` is in the plan for emacs 73. Right after `M-x write-app`.

Comment: If it could be written down as an algorithm, even one algorithm per language, someone would have codified it, I am sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark a region and call `M-x indent-region` -- that will indent the code which comprises parens (and more).

Comment: *sigh* since switching to python I miss being able to do this.

Comment: I just tried and it works for me in the (default) Python mode in Emacs23. What do you use?

Comment: @Dirk thanks for your answer (I use the equivalent M-x \\) but I don't understand how that automates the fixing of mismatched parens?

Comment: David, can you maybe rephrase your question and explain what *fixing parens* means to you if it is not covered by reindentation?

Comment: @Dirk - thanks, will do; I meant, if my code won't compile because it is missing a paren

Comment: I would go with Trey and the very first comment:  you are overestimating what Emacs and Elisp, even with all the AI ;-), can do.  It is not going to be writing code for you.